# Reading a txt file, split string then write to txt file

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have a text file call groceries. That contain text similar to the following:

```
regular,cereal,4.00,1;
fresh,rump steak,11.99,0.8;
```

The code below is trying to read the text file, split the string and then write to a text file called invoice.
The invoice text file should read read line in the groceries file, list whether it is a "fresh" or "regular" grocery item. If fresh GST is not applied if regular GST is applied.  Calculate the cost on weight for fresh and quantity for regular and then display a total cost of items listed.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Groceries3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] groceries = File.ReadAllLines ("Groceries.txt");
            File.WriteAllLines("Invoice.txt", invoices.ToArray());

            List<string> invoices = new List<string>();
            FreshGrocery freshGrocery = new FreshGrocery();
            freshGrocery.Name = "fresh";
            freshGrocery.Price = 30;
            freshGrocery.Weight = 0.5;
            Grocery grocery = new Grocery();
            grocery.Name = "regular";
            grocery.Price = 50;
            grocery.Quantity = 2;

            double price = price.Calculate();

            int counter = 0;
             foreach (var grocery2 in groceries)
             {
                counter++;
                invoices.Add(counter + "," + grocery + price+Quantity+"," + DateTime.Now.Date);
             }
                 abstract class GroceryItem
        {
            private string name;
            private double price = 0;

            public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return name;
                }
                set
                {
                    name = value;
                }
            }
            public double Price
            {
                get
                {
                    return price;
                }
                set
                {
                    price = value;
                }
            }
            public abstract double Calculate();
        }
        class FreshGrocery : GroceryItem
        {
            private double weight = 0;
            public double Weight
            {
                get
                {
                    return weight;
                }
                set
                {
                    weight = value;
                }
            }
            public override double Calculate()
            {
                return this.Price * this.weight;
            }
        }
        class Grocery : GroceryItem
        {
            private int quantity = 0;
            private double gst = 10;

            public int Quantity
            {
                get
                {
                    return quantity;
                }
                set
                {
                    quantity = value;
                }
            }
            public override double Calculate()
            {
                double calculatedPrice = this.Price * this.Quantity;
                if (calculatedPrice < 0)
                {
                    calculatedPrice += calculatedPrice * (gst / 100);
                }
                 return calculatedPrice;
            }
        }
        class ShoppingCart
        {
            private List<GroceryItem> orders;

            public List<GroceryItem> Orders
            {
                get
                {
                    return orders;
                }
                set
                {
                    orders = value;
                }
            }
             public double Calculate()
            {
                double price = 0;
                if (this.Orders != null)
                {
                    foreach (GroceryItem order in this.Orders)
                    {
                        price += order.Calculate();
                    }
                }
                return price;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difficulty that you are facing with the current code? are you getting any error or exception?

Comment: This code is not compiling ! You are using invoices in your second line, but  the invoice definition is in your 3rd line.

Comment: There's a missing closing bracket for your `Main` method also. I guess you are not using notepad to code. So why don't you check your errors in visual studio? I mean the informations are very obvious. `WriteAllLines` has to be placed after your `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.  I am trying to calculate the total cost for all items in the groceries.txt file and write to the invoices.txt

Comment: How would i add all the freshGrocery.Price and all the price to create a "Total price of all groceries: {0}" in the invoice file?  at the moment I have: File.AppendAllText("Invoice.txt", string.Format("{0}{1}", "Total of all groceries ={0}", Environment.NewLine));

Answer (score 0):

try something like that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Groceries3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] groceries = File.ReadAllLines("Groceries.txt");
            List<string> invoices = new List<string>();

            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var grocery2 in groceries)
            {
                counter++;
                var list = grocery2.Split(',');
                if (list[0].Equals("fresh"))
                {
                    FreshGrocery freshGrocery = new FreshGrocery();
                    freshGrocery.Name = list[1];
                    freshGrocery.Price = double.Parse(list[2]);
                    freshGrocery.Weight = double.Parse(list[3].Replace(";", ""));

                    invoices.Add(counter + "," + freshGrocery.Name + "," + freshGrocery.Price + "," + freshGrocery.Weight + "," + DateTime.Now.Date);
                }
                else if (list[0].Equals("regular"))
                {
                    Grocery grocery = new Grocery();
                    grocery.Name = list[1];
                    grocery.Price = double.Parse(list[2]);
                    grocery.Quantity = int.Parse(list[3].Replace(";", ""));

                    double price = grocery.Calculate();
                    invoices.Add(counter + "," + grocery.Name + "," + price + "," + grocery.Quantity + "," + DateTime.Now.Date);
                }
            }

            File.WriteAllLines("Invoice.txt", invoices.ToArray());
        }

        abstract class GroceryItem
        {
            private string name;
            private double price = 0;

            public string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return name;
                }
                set
                {
                    name = value;
                }
            }
            public double Price
            {
                get
                {
                    return price;
                }
                set
                {
                    price = value;
                }
            }
            public abstract double Calculate();
        }

        class FreshGrocery : GroceryItem
        {
            private double weight = 0;
            public double Weight
            {
                get
                {
                    return weight;
                }
                set
                {
                    weight = value;
                }
            }
            public override double Calculate()
            {
                return this.Price * this.weight;
            }
        }

        class Grocery : GroceryItem
        {
            private int quantity = 0;
            private double gst = 10;

            public int Quantity
            {
                get
                {
                    return quantity;
                }
                set
                {
                    quantity = value;
                }
            }
            public override double Calculate()
            {
                double calculatedPrice = this.Price * this.Quantity;
                if (calculatedPrice < 0)
                {
                    calculatedPrice += calculatedPrice * (gst / 100);
                }
                 return calculatedPrice;
            }
        }
        class ShoppingCart
        {
            private List<GroceryItem> orders;

            public List<GroceryItem> Orders
            {
                get
                {
                    return orders;
                }
                set
                {
                    orders = value;
                }
            }
            public double Calculate()
            {
                double price = 0;
                if (this.Orders != null)
                {
                    foreach (GroceryItem order in this.Orders)
                    {
                        price += order.Calculate();
                    }
                }
                return price;
            }
        }
    }
}
```